# Как работает данный запрос? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Понадобилось написать SQL запрос на выбор случайной записи, не долго думая открыл документацию MySQL, почитал про рандом и получилось вот это

```
SELECT * FROM `Task` WHERE id = (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (SELECT Count(`id`) FROM `Task`)))
```

В первый раз все ок(Повезло), потом 3 записи, потом 0, ну и так далее...
Почему?

Comment: как 3 записи? У вас id не уникальный? Не primary key?

Comment: vp_arth, даже если и не Primary (он Primary) Там стоит условия выборки

Comment: `limit 1` делай и не парься))) а вообще неплохо было бы это наглядно увидеть, например можешь на http://sqlfiddle.com/ положить и сюда ссылку дать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я лимит ставил (Окей 1 костыль), но бывает что выпадает 0 записей и это не из-за рандома (Спавнит 1 - n), даже знаю как это решить. Но получится уже 2 костыля, а это уже не прикольно )

Comment: `limit 1`, `count` заменить на `max`, а `=` на `<` и `floor` убрать. Иначе от пустых выборок не избавиться, и строкам с `id>count(id)` удача не светит

Comment: Я так понял что всё же 3 записи у вас выпадали по раздельности. Неочевидно же. `where pk = (что бы то ни было)` не может вернуть больше одной записи

Comment: @vp_arth я вас правильно понял?
`SELECT * FROM Task WHERE id < (1 + (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Task)));`

Comment: Вот так будет точнее. `SELECT * FROM Task WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM Task ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` но рандом тут нифига не равномерный)

Comment: наверняка в id есть разрывы нумерации. вы просто получаете случайное число которого нет в таблице и в итоге 0 записей.

Comment: @Mike 
 > наверняка в id есть разрывы нумерации
 - нет все с 1 по n с шагом + 1

Comment: @Mike
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0843/1
Ну вроде все правильно сделал

Comment: @Mike
11  -   1   -  11

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0843/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL ради каждой записи заново вычисляет значение случайного числа. посмотрим что происходит:

```
SELECT id, (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * ((SELECT Count(id) FROM Test)))) rnd
  FROM Test
```

результат:

```
'1', '4'
'2', '12'
'3', '10'
'4', '12'
'5', '8'
'6', '1'
'7', '5'
'8', '10'
'9', '9'
'10', '11'
'11', '9'
'12', '12'
```

А теперь накладываем на это наш фильтр `id=rnd`, на выходе строки:

```
'9', '9'
'12', '12'
```

Итого 2 записи. Просто так сложилось, что на момент выбора этих id из БД `rand()` дала точно такое же значение и условие сработало. Если нам не повезет `rand()` может ни для одной строки не дать совпадающего значения.

Так будет надежно:

```
SELECT id
  FROM Test, (select (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * ((SELECT Count(id) FROM Test)))) rnd) X
 WHERE id=rnd
```

В данном случае MySQL сначала вычислит (один раз) `rand()`, а потом будет искать запись с нужным id.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне даже просто было интересно почему не работало, теперь ясно.